# knife status to list node where chef is failing

Tags: automation, knife, chef-infra

I was looking a way to list chef-client where chef is failing (Only failing NOT stopped).

I checked knife status document, but didn't find anything usefull.

anyone know better way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to how `knife status --hide-healthy` doesn't do what you want? Do you need more detail about failed runs?

Comment: I want to list nodes where chef-client is failing, I don't want to see where chef-client is stopped purposely in that list.

Comment: This post is kind of interesting (see the comments as well), as a method to see the last check in time that was successful. http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/02/16/last-check-in-time-for-nodes/

Comment: Thanks for the link. My understanding of "Last Check-in Time for Nodes" is when chef-client runs successful it connects to server and updates its status. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The knife [lastrun](https://github.com/jgoulah/knife-lastrun) plugin provides a useful chef handler that will record the time and status of most recent chef run. It will also usefully store the stack trace of any failed chef run. This is useful plugin when running large numbers of chef clients.